# Obtaining `Show a` from the context `Show (a,b)`

Tags: haskell, typeclass

As the title says, I'm interested in using `Show a` in a context where I have `Show (a,b)`. This problem easily arises with GADTs as follows:

```
data PairOrNot a where
  Pair :: (b,c) -> PairOrNot (b,c)
  Not :: a -> PairOrNot a

showFirstIfPair :: Show a => PairOrNot a -> String
showFirstIfPair (Not a) = show a
showFirstIfPair (Pair (b,c)) = show b
```

The error is:

```
Could not deduce (Show b) arising from a use of ‘show’
from the context (Show a)
  bound by the type signature for
             showFirstIfPair :: Show a => PairOrNot a -> String
  at app/Main.hs:24:20-50
or from (a ~ (b, c))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             Pair :: forall b c. (b, c) -> PairOrNot (b, c),
           in an equation for ‘showFirstIfPair’
  at app/Main.hs:26:18-27
Possible fix:
  add (Show b) to the context of the data constructor ‘Pair’
In the expression: show b
In an equation for ‘showFirstIfPair’:
    showFirstIfPair (Pair (b, c)) = show b
```

I'd think the instance declaration `instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)` proves `Show element`, but I can also imagine that the problem also has something to do with how the typeclass machinery is implemented at runtime.

I've discovered that if we can modify the class definition it's possible to solve this via:

```
class Show' a where
  show' :: a -> String
  unpair :: a -> Dict (a ~ (b,c)) -> Dict (Show' b, Show' c)

-- An example non-pair instance
instance Show' Int where
  show' i = ""
  unpair = undefined -- This is OK, since no one can construct Dict (Int ~ (b,c))

instance (Show' a, Show' b) => Show' (a,b) where
  show' (a,b) = ""
  unpair _ Dict = Dict -- In this context we have access to Show' for elems
```

Then at the use site, we fetch the dictionary explicitly:

```
showFirstIfPair :: Show' a => PairOrNot a -> String
showFirstIfPair (Not a) = show' a
showFirstIfPair (Pair a@(b,c)) = 
  case unpair a Dict of -- This is a Dict (a~(b,c))
    Dict -> show' b -- This is Dict (Show' b,Show' c)
```

I was wondering if there is a non-intrusive (or just different) way of obtaining `Show element`. If not, could you explain why exactly this problem is arising?

Comment: Well, you must know `(Show b, Show c)` in order to construct the dictionary `Show (b, c)`. So at the point where you construct the `Pair` you could instead just extract the first element

Comment: Your question implies you have the context `Show a, Show b => ...` but your code only has `Show a => ...` hence the error about not being able to deduce `Show b`.

Comment: You are mixing up the meaning of typeclass entailment. `Show a, Show b => Show (a,b)` means that `Show a` and `Show b` together give rise to a `Show (a,b)` but it doesn't necessarily mean the opposite holds. For example, consider two types `X, Y`, with an `instance Show (X, Y)` - you don't *necessarily* have an `instance (Show X)` here, because `show` could be `const ""`. What your `unpair` function is doing is giving a proof of the property you want, which is exactly what you must do if you want to use said property.

Comment: @user2407038 Maybe I'm looking at it from the wrong mental framework, if `Z` is true if and only if `X` and `Y`, doesn't `Z` imply both `X` and `Y`? Maybe I shouldn't be thinking of it at it as a logic statement.

Comment: @user2407038 I see, so, if `OverlappingInstances` were turned on, someone could define a rogue `instance Show (X, Y)` without `Show X` or `Show Y`.

Comment: @enobayram The logical statement `A /\ B => C` means that both `A` and `B` together are a sufficient condition for `C`, which says *nothing* about what occurs in regards to `A` and `B` when `C` definitely holds. It does not state that `C` holds if and only if `A /\ B`. What you are describing is usually written `A /\ B <=> C` or `A /\ B == C`.

Comment: @Lee You're mistaken, I have the context `(Show a, a ~ (b,c))` and I need `Show b`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Sure, but that means I have to modify the data definition

Comment: @enobayram Yes, I believe you would need `OverlappingInstances` somewhere for the specific example I gave - but the point is that the compiler *cannot* assume that `Show (a,b)` came from `(Show a, Show b)` no matter what you do, because this assumption is simply not sound. This is just the open world assumption for typeclasses in a somewhat sneaky form.

Comment: @user2407038 Well, if the compiler could assume both open-world and no-overlaps, it could infer `Show a` from `Show (a,b)`. But Haskell wants to allow the possibility of overlaps, hence it must disallow this unsound inference.

Comment: @chi, GHC Haskell wants to allow the possibility of open overlaps. Some Haskellers, like myself, think it's a horrible idea. However, there are good implementation reasons to refrain from offering entailment based on instance constraints. The constraint dictionary (for a class constraint) can be inlined into the instance dictionary and not passed around at runtime. GHC Core seems to represent an instance with context as a function from dictionaries to a dictionary. Given `f x y`, you can't expect to recover `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the restriction that `b` must always be an instance of `Show`, then this is a simple solution:

```
data PairOrNot a where
  Pair :: Show b => (b,c) -> PairOrNot (b,c)
  Not :: a -> PairOrNot a
```

Comment: I don't know why your answer was downvoted, after all I indicated that I'm open to different solutions, and this solution isn't any more intrusive than my own solution. I intrude the type class, you intrude the data definition.

Comment: Thanks. The downvote was probably because adding constraints to constructors is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @user2297560 No it is not frowned upon, AFAIK. What is frowned upon is constraining data type constructors, like `data Show a => T a =  ...` since that has a questionable, inconvenient semantics. (It is true, though, that by doing `Pair :: Show b => ...` we make the constructor to operationally pack one more pointer, increasing the memory footprint of the value representation)

Comment: @user2297560 No, That's the whole point of GADTs: having a good way of adding constraints to value constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I've kept trying to see if I can come up with something better, and here's the best I could come up with:

In my original attempt, I've coupled the `Show'` type class with the instance declaration for pairs. Even though I couldn't find a way around modifying the type class, I've at least managed to generalize this for any instance declaration.

As pointed out in the question's comments `instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)` is a one-way implication, but I assumed it could be applied in the other direction as well, given the absence of overlapping instances. Unfortunately GHC doesn't rely on that, but we can assert that ourselves. My intuition can be translated into code: (`:=>` is from `Data.Constraint` from the `constraints` package, and `a :=> b` means that there is an `instance a => b` somewhere)

```
class Show' a where
  show' :: a -> String
  noOverlap :: (b :=> Show' a) => Proxy a -> Dict b
```

Here, the `noOverlap` function is a promise that if you can find a constraint `b` which gives rise to an instance `Show' a`, I can prove `b` given `Show' a`. This promise is equivalent to stating that there will be no overlapping instances for `Show'`

Now, we need a helper function to actually implement `noOverlap`

```
basedOn :: forall k a. (k :=> Show' a, k) => 
             (forall b. (b :=> Show' a) => Proxy a -> Dict b)
basedOn _ = unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict k)
```

What this function does is that, if you call it in a context where you have an instance `k :=> Show' a`, it will return a function that will return `Dict b` for **any** instance `b :=> Show' a`. We have to use `unsafeCoerce` to convince GHC that `Dict k` and `Dict b` are the same, but as far as I can see, this is a safe use of unsafeCoerce, since the functional dependency `a :=> b | b -> a` makes sure that there can be only one instance of `k :=> Show' a` for a given `Show' a`.

Now, given this helper, here's how you define instances

```
-- An example non-pair instance
instance () :=> Show' Int where ins = Sub Dict 
instance        Show' Int where
  show' i = ""
  noOverlap = basedOn

instance (Show' a, Show' b) :=> Show' (a,b) where ins = Sub Dict
instance (Show' a, Show' b)  => Show' (a,b) where
  show' (a,b) = ""
  noOverlap = basedOn -- GHC does all the plumbing here
```

We have to define the `:=>` instances manually, since GHC doesn't do it automatically, but there's no room for error there. If we give a too weak constraint on the left of a manually defined `:=>`, `ins = Sub Dict` will fail to compile and if we give a too strong constraint, then `noOverlap = basedOn` will fail to compile, so that boilerplate is forced by the compiler.

We can then use `noOverlap` as follows:

```
showFirstIfPair :: Show' a => PairOrNot a -> String
showFirstIfPair (Not a) = show' a
showFirstIfPair (Pair a@(b,c)) = 
  -- In this context we have (Show' b, Show' c) :=> Show' a
  case noOverlap Proxy of -- This is a Proxy a
    Dict -> show' b -- This is a Dict (Show' b, Show' c)
```

The nice thing is that, now we can also go from, say, `Show' [a]` to `Show' a`, or any other instance declaration.

Note: You'll need `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeOperators, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}` to compile these.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, it's working. `noOverlap _ = Dict` won't work, because the fundep in `:=>` is not enough to convince GHC for an equality, but we're asserting the equality with the `unsafeCoerce` in `basedOn` ourselves. I guess it'd be quite hard to violate that `unsafeCoerce` even if you tried.

Comment: Argh! I misread what you were doing. I thought you were coercing something else. Sorry! You might want to consider using this type, for clarity: `basedOn :: forall k a b. (k :=> Show' a, b :=> Show' a) => proxy a -> Dict k -> Dict b`. Since this coerces the dictionary based on the assumption that the fundep actually holds (not an entirely safe assumption), you could even go further and use `assertThin :: forall k l c. (k :=> c, l :=> c) => proxy c -> k :~: l` without (I believe) any further loss of safety.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalisation of [user2297560](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640735/745903) that's doesn't require hard-coding `Show` in the GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data PairOrNot (cl :: * -> Constraint) (a :: *) where
  Pair :: (cl b, cl c) => (b,c) -> PairOrNot (b,c)
  Not :: cl a => a -> PairOrNot a
```

Then you can

```
showFirstIfPair :: PairOrNot Show a -> String
showFirstIfPair (Not a) = show a
showFirstIfPair (Pair (b,c)) = show b
```

Comment: That's better, but it's still coupling a concrete type `PairOrNot cl a` with the set `cl` of constraints passed to it. In my case, I do need `PairOrNot a` to be parametric for `a` without any constrains. I just need `(Show b, Show c)` from `Show (b,c)` in those contexts where I know `Show a`.

Comment: @enobayram, if you only care about `Show`, then you can show the pair and then try to extract the relevant portion of the string. It's horrible, of course.